How to run docker in Jenkins deployed in Kubernetes cluster?
I have a deployed Jenkins instance in Kubernetes.
In addition to that, the worker nodes are spawn as pods.
I am wondering if there is a possibility to run a docker inside the those pods (to run Testcontainers).
I was able to install docker inside ubuntu or alpine nodes, but I encountered a following problem:
# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I found that there is something like: Docker in Docker, where you can run something like this:
docker run -dit --restart=always -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ltscustomjenkins

acording to: https://medium.com/@yassine.essadraoui_78000/jenkins-docker-in-docker-b7630c7b9364
but it doesn't sound helpful for my case.

Just add another container to agent definition like that:

- name: build-container
    image: image1
    ...
- name: test-container
    image: image2
    ...

and connect to it via localhost.
If it does not answer your question, could you give me more information about your configuration and requirements?
